# Away3D 4.0 TextureMaterial activateForDepth()

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I am new to Away3D, and I’m using version 4.1.1b.

I am having trouble with the rendering order of Meshes added to the scene.
(Objects in the distance are rendering infront of Objects closer to the Camera)
I found that in version 4.0 you could call `activateForDepth()` on a `TextureMaterial`.
It seems as though this method has been removed.
Can someone please point me towards how to fix this in 4.1.1.

I have also tried,

```
_view.renderer = new DepthRenderer( true, true );
```

This seems to fix the depth/distance problem, but everything is bright blue with circles instead of textures.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been solved, for anyone looking for the answer see this other post.

http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/4673/